# pass data from one component to another component using class reference?

Tags: angular

I have Angular components and first component i want to call html class from one component to another class. How can I pass that model to the second component?

Rate Card i  want call another component html class on onclick

Comment: Please provide code :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.